# How to dynamically change object's property type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have JavaScript function which loop through the `span` collection and dynamically creates an object.

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="property" data-propetyname="Day" data-propertyvalue="10"></span>
    <span class="property" data-propetyname="Year" data-propertyvalue="2015"></span>
    <span class="property" data-propetyname="Year" data-propertyvalue="2016"></span>
    <span class="property" data-propetyname="Month" data-propertyvalue="12"></span>
</div>


$(function ()
{
    function getData() {
        var data = {};
        $('#container').find('.property').each(function (index, value) {
            var property = $(value);
            var name = property.data('propetyname');
            var val = property.data('propertyvalue');
            data[name] = val;
        })

        return data;
    }
})
```

In the code above, if the property already exists on the object then it overwrites the value. What I want is, if the property already exists then it should convert the property's type to array and push the value into it. For example, in above scenario the `Year` property should get converted to array with 2 values `2015` and `2016`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$(function ()
{
    function getData() {
        var data = {};
        $('#container').find('.property').each(function (index, value) {
            var property = $(value);
            var name = property.data('propetyname');
            var val = property.data('propertyvalue');

            if (!(name in data)) {
                data[name] = val; // new property
            } else if (data[name].constructor === Array) {
                data[name].push(val); // property is already an array
            } else {
               data[name] = [data[name], val]; // change property to array
            }
        })

        return data;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function ()
{
    function getData() {
        var data = {};
        $('#container').find('.property').each(function (index, value) {
            var property = $(value);
            var name = property.data('propetyname');
            var val = property.data('propertyvalue');

            if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                 if (!Array.isArray(data[name])) {
                      data[name] = [data[name]]; // convert to array!
                 }
                 data[name].push(val);
            }
            else {
                 data[name] = val;
            }
        })

        return data;
    }
})
```

Note `Array.isArray` is only present in IE9+, otherwise use another array-detection strategy.

Answer (score 2):

First, you check if the object has the property already

```
if (data[name]) {
```

Then, you check if the object is already an array

```
  if(data[name].constructor === Array) {
```

If it is, you can just push your value to the array.

```
      data[name].push(val);
```

Otherwise

```
  } else {
```

Put the existing element into a new array, and assign it to the property

```
    data[name] = [data[name],val];
  }
```

And if the variable is not already an array

```
} else {
```

Just assign val to it.

```
  data[name] = val;
}
```

That said, I think there are some possible design improvements to be made to this code. First of all, I wouldn't store a single element as a single variable when you expect that there could be multiple values. You could more easily store it as the first element of an array, and then your assigning code would be simpler, as would the code that accesses this array.

Answer (score 1):

here's a similar approach to the other suggestions, using plain Javascript (no jQuery requierd):

This solution does the following:

- If the property is an array, it just pushes the new element to that array.
- If the property is a string or a number, it converts the value of that property to an array with one element (the current value) and then pushes the new element to that array.
- If the property doesn't exist, is empty or null, it just sets that property to the new value.

```js
(function() {
  function getData() {
    var data = {};

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#container .property'),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var property = elements[i];
      var name = property.getAttribute('data-propertyname');
      var value = property.getAttribute('data-propertyvalue');


      if (data[name] instanceof Array) {
        data[name].push(value);
      } else if (typeof data[name] === 'string' || typeof data[name] === 'number') {
        data[name] = [data[name]];
        data[name].push(value);
      } else {
        data[name] = value;
      }
    }
    
    return data;
  }

  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getData());
})();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="property" data-propertyname="Day" data-propertyvalue="10"></span>
  <span class="property" data-propertyname="Year" data-propertyvalue="2015"></span>
  <span class="property" data-propertyname="Year" data-propertyvalue="2016"></span>
  <span class="property" data-propertyname="Month" data-propertyvalue="12"></span>
</div>

<pre></pre>
```